# d3: How to properly chain transitions on different selections

Tags: animation, d3.js, transition

I am using V3 of the popular d3 library and basically want to have three transitions, followed by each other: The first transition should apply to the exit selection, the second to the update selection and the third to the enter selection. They should be chained in such a manner that when one of the selections is empty, its respective transition is skipped. I.e. when there is no exit selection, the update selection should start immediately. So far, I have come up with this code (using the `delay` function).

```
// DATA JOIN
var items = d3.select('#data').selectAll('.item');
items = items.data(data, function(d){ 
    return d.twitter_screenname;
});


// EXIT
items.exit().transition().duration(TRANSITION_DURATION).style('opacity', 0).remove();

// UPDATE
// Divs bewegen
items.transition().duration(TRANSITION_DURATION).delay(TRANSITION_DURATION * 1)
    .style('left', function(d, i) {
        return positions[i].left + "px";
    }).style('top', function(d, i) {
        return positions[i].top + "px";
    });

// ENTER
// Divs hinzufügen
var div = items.enter().append('div')
    .attr('class', 'item')
    .style('left', function(d, i) {
        return positions[i].left + "px";
    }).style('top', function(d, i) {
        return positions[i].top + "px";
    });

 div.style('opacity', 0)
    .transition().duration(TRANSITION_DURATION).delay(TRANSITION_DURATION * 2)
    .style('opacity', 1);
```

First of all it doesn't allow to "skip" transitions and secondly I think there is a better way than `delay`. I've looked at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3903818 but I did not really understand what is happening.

Also, somehow just writing `items.exit().transition().duration(TRANSITION_DURATION).remove()` does not work with the `items`, probably because they are not SVG elements but `div`s.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Sure. Here are two ways.

First, you could use an explicit [delay](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-delay), which you then compute using [selection.empty](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-empty) to skip empty transitions. (This is only a minor modification of what you have already.)

```
var div = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(["enter", "update"], function(d) { return d || this.textContent; });

// 2. update
div.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .delay(!div.exit().empty() * duration)
    .style("background", "orange");

// 3. enter
div.enter().append("div")
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
    .style("opacity", 0)
  .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .delay((!div.exit().empty() + !div.enter().empty()) * duration)
    .style("background", "green")
    .style("opacity", 1);

// 1. exit
div.exit()
    .style("background", "red")
  .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove();
```

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5779682

One tricky thing here is that you have to create the transition on the updating elements *before* you create the transition on the entering elements; that’s because [enter.append](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-enter) merges entering elements into the update selection, and you want to keep them separate; see the [Update-only Transition example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3900925) for details.

Alternatively, you could use [transition.transition](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-transition) to [chain transitions](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3903818), and [transition.each](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-each) to apply these chained transitions to existing selections. Within the context of transition.each, selection.transition inherits the existing transition rather than creating a new one.

```
var div = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(["enter", "update"], function(d) { return d || this.textContent; });

// 1. exit
var exitTransition = d3.transition().duration(750).each(function() {
  div.exit()
      .style("background", "red")
    .transition()
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .remove();
});

// 2. update
var updateTransition = exitTransition.transition().each(function() {
  div.transition()
      .style("background", "orange");
});

// 3. enter
var enterTransition = updateTransition.transition().each(function() {
  div.enter().append("div")
      .text(function(d) { return d; })
      .style("opacity", 0)
    .transition()
      .style("background", "green")
      .style("opacity", 1);
});
```

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5779690

I suppose the latter is a bit more idiomatic, although using transition.each to apply transitions to selections (rather than derive transitions with default parameters) isn’t a widely-known feature.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think there's a small error in your code using the `delay()`-Method. When there is no update transition (i.e. no elements change place), `items.enter().empty()` still equals `false`, so elemens exit, then, for `duration` milliseconds nothing happens, and then the enter transition starts. But if there is no visual update transition taking place, I want the exit transition to be followed *immediately* by the enter transition. I thus save the update transition as follows:

Comment: `var updatedItems = div.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .delay(!div.exit().empty() * duration)` and change `.delay((!div.exit().empty() + !div.enter().empty()) * duration)` into `.delay((!div.exit().empty() + !updatedItems.empty()) * duration)`. This way it works as required.